# Add a "Ship To" column in Woocommerce "My Account" orders table

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to add a column that displays the 'Ship to' company name to the WooCommerce > my account > orders page.

So far the code below adds a column but how do I get the 'Ship to' data to show, where am I'm I getting it wrong?

```html
 // Add new column(s) to the "My Orders" table in the account.
function filter_woocommerce_account_orders_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['custom-column'] = __( 'New Column 1', 'woocommerce' );
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'filter_woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 10, 1 );

 // Adds data to the custom column in "My Account > Orders"
function filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_shipping_company_column( $order ) {    
    echo 'New Column 1';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom-column', 'filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_custom_column', 10, 1 );

 $order_shipping_company = $order_data['shipping']['company'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query` filter hook. You have to pass a number of orders you want to display to `numberposts` param. try below code.

```
function modify_numberposts_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query( $customer_orders_args ){
    $customer_orders_args['numberposts'] = 20;
    return $customer_orders_args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'modify_numberposts_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query' );
```

Comment: Bhautik - thank you thank you thank you thank you !!!!!! this worked PERFECT!!!! I changed it from 20 to 2000 now my users can see all their orders.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered it : FINALLY !!

```html
function sv_wc_add_my_account_orders_column( $columns ) {

    $new_columns = array();

    foreach ( $columns as $key => $name ) {

        $new_columns[ $key ] = $name;

        // add ship-to after order status column
        if ( 'order-status' === $key ) {
            $new_columns['order-ship-to'] = __( 'Ship to', 'textdomain' );
        }
    }

    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'sv_wc_add_my_account_orders_column' );


/**
 * Adds data to the custom "ship to" column in "My Account > Orders".
 *
 * @param \WC_Order $order the order object for the row
 */
function sv_wc_my_orders_ship_to_column( $order ) {

    $formatted_shipping = $order->get_formatted_shipping_address();

    echo ! empty( $formatted_shipping ) ? $formatted_shipping : '&ndash;';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_order-ship-to', 'sv_wc_my_orders_ship_to_column' );
```